# Spring boot application which works on local tomcat gives 404 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Spring boot application works just fine on my locally installed Tomcat server. But when I deploy the same WAR to the Elastic Beanstalk and click the given URL, all I get is 404. No route specified in my Spring Boot application works here. What could be the possible reason?

server.port = 5000

Comment: did you check the AWS CDN configuration. also try to enable logs on debug mode and check

Comment: I think I am not using CDN right now. All I did is simply deploying to the Elastic BeanStalk

Comment: Did you follow the instructions mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html)?

Comment: @sachin-titus elastibeanstalk by default it use's CDN

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes I followed the documentation as is

Comment: @Rajesh I did not find CDN in AWS. Could you provide links please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your application as ROOT.war then I guess the base path will be  myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/ or else if it is a path directly beneath it (eg app2.war) then it will run at myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/app2/

[Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html)